# SPARQL date range

Tags: sparql

I'm trying to obtain all records between certain dates. The date field has appears in this format: `2012-01-31`. I think it is of type: `<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date>`

How would I modify the query below to extract records with date greater than 2012-01-31 please?

```
PREFIX xsd:     <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX owl:     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX lrppi:   <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ppi/>
PREFIX skos:    <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX lrcommon: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/common/>

SELECT  ?county ?postcode ?amount ?date
WHERE
{    
    ?transx  lrppi:pricePaid ?amount .
    ?transx   lrppi:transactionDate ?date .
    ?transx   lrppi:propertyAddress ?addr.

    ?addr lrcommon:postcode "PL6 8RU"^^xsd:string .
    ?addr lrcommon:postcode ?postcode .

    # Cant get this line to work
    # ?date lrppi:transactionDate ?date . FILTER ( ?date >= "1327968000"^^xsd:date  )

    OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:county ?county .}
}
ORDER BY ?postcode
```

If you want to play with this, you can enter your query here:
http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/landregistry/sparql/sparql.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what the `FILTER` clause is designed for.

The [Expressions and Testing Values](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#expressions) section of the SPARQL specification covers this in detail, pretty much the first example in that section covers filtering on dates.

### Edit

If you are new to SPARQL then I would recommend you read a good SPARQL tutorial like [SPARQL by Example](http://www.cambridgesemantics.com/semantic-university/sparql-by-example) which is written by one of the specification authors.  This will walk you through various parts of SPARQL and should help you get your head around the RDF data model and query language better.

In terms of dates they are represented using [XML schema datatypes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/), for example expressing today as a date would be the following:

```
"2013-03-22"^^xsd:date
```

The linked specification covers the lexical form of various datatypes.

So for your example it would be the following:

```
FILTER ( ?date >= "2012-01-31"^^xsd:date )
```

If you are starting from a UNIX timestamp and trying to get to an `xsd:date` see [Generating an xsd:dateTime in shell script](https://web.archive.org/web/20131030075739/http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/20716/generating-an-xsddatetime-in-shell-script) which may provide a useful starting point.

Comment: Thanks RobV. I came across the filter command and tried it out, but couldnt get it to work. See updated question. I'm not sure how to work out how the date is stored and how to convert to unix timestamp and how exactly I format the query. The main problem is that I've just started on SPARQL today and cant get my head round it. Especially as I cant figure out exactly what the source of the data looks like (i.e. where the columns come from, what format the data is in).

Comment: @spiderplant0 I've added some more detail to my question, hopefully this will help get you going