# Date filter on SPARQL using R

Tags: r, date, filter, sparql

I am currently writing a block of code on R which collects data via a SPARQL query. My problem is when I am trying to filter the query by date, R gives an error of "unexpected numeric constant".
There is no any mistake in the SPARQL code because when I run the exact code on the endpoint I receive data normally.

You will find the block of code where I have the problem. It does not matter the lines before and after, just the second line of the date filter.

```
...
OPTIONAL {?seller gr:legalName ?sellerLegalName} .
FILTER REGEX (STR(?date) >= "2015-01-01") .
FILTER NOT EXISTS {?spendingItem elod:hasCorrectedDecision ?correctedDecision} .
...
```

Please, I would kindly ask for your help! :)
For any further information that you want in order to solve the problem, feel free to contact with me.

Thank you all!!!

---

## **SOLVED!**

I found that the date should be passed as timestamp!
Also, I found a useful [site](http://www.timestampgenerator.com/1420063200/#result) where you can convert any date in timestamp and vice versa.

I would like to thank you all for your responses and your useful help!

Comment: Certainly doesn't look like any R code I've ever seen.

Comment: Does that query (with FILTER REGEX (STR(?date) >= "2015-01-01") ) really work?

Comment: This is not the R code. This code is 3 lines of the query that is embedded in the R code. It's the first part where I collect the data and after that I do the statistical analysis in R. When I delete the filter of date, all work fine! But I need this.. The query is working on the endpoint. When I try to run it through the R, then the "unexpected numerical constant" error appears and I can not continue grabbing data..

Comment: In that case you would have to supply more information - ideally all the parts involved - full SPARQL query, R code and RDF data (or SPARQL endpoint) that you are working with. That way someone can repeat the problem. Use https://gist.github.com/ for sharing longer code fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You should filter it as a date/time value rather than as a string - perhaps that will help:

```
FILTER (?date > "2015-01-01"^^xsd:date)
```

See this answer: [SPARQL date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573814/sparql-date-range?rq=1)

Comment: Unfortunately, still the problem exists... :( It does not recognize it even as a string or as a date. Thanks for your help!!! I am not familiar with SPARQL but I can understand that all these ways are correct. I can not find the mistake that R reveals... Is there any other way to filter the date?

Comment: You could also get unfiltered data from SPARQL query and filter it in R.

Comment: I have already thought of it but the problem is that I want to receive filtered data due to the fact that a user will ask about different dates. In that case I have to change the filter in R manually. But if I will receive filtered data, I will just write the script of statistical analysis of any data without carrying about the date which will be stated by the user.

* Sorry if I can not explain exactly what I want to do.. Feel free to ask for furhter information! :) Thanks for your help!